# Access shared disk on a router from another connected router

Tags: wireless-router, nas, home-networking, switch, shared-folders

Here is the set up diagram:  
                                `Modem
                                  |
                                  |
                      Router A (Serve as a switch)
                                  /\
                                 /  \
                                /    \
                           Desktop   Router B (with shared disk)`

Is it possible for me to access the shared disk on Router B locally from my Desktop without directly connecting to it? Is Port Forwarding a potential solution?

I've been trying to find answers online for so long but had no luck :( Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it is incredibly simple. Just set Router B to use "Access Point mode" (AP mode). This will disable Router B's DHCP and will put Desktop and Router B in the same network domain.

Comment: You don’t even need anything like that. You can disable DHCP manually, match the subnet and connect to a LAN port (instead of WAN) on Router B. That would work with virtually any router.